# How does editing a user's role in spring security modify the user's password/access?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, bcrypt

When I edit a user's roles through a page in my application it somehow modifies the user's password. I cant for the life of me figure out where I am changing the user's password in my code. I even went so far as to print out the hashed password after I call Save in the user service and they still match! But when I log out and try to log back in with the user's same credentials Spring says the credentials are invalid. Oddly enough, this only happens when I change the roles, if I change just the name or email address the issue doesn't present.

This is my save method in userServiceImpl

```
@Override
    public void save(User user) {
        System.out.println("User trying to save");
        user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
```

And this is the controller for editing (I know it's a mess and needs to be cleaned up A LOT!)

```
@PostMapping("/users/edit")
    public String editUser(@ModelAttribute("userForm") User user, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("highestRole", getHighestRole(user.getUserName(), userService));
        model.addAttribute("pageTitle", "AIM - Edit User Id:" + user.getId());
        model.addAllAttributes(getUserAttributes());
        model.addAttribute("roles", roleRepository.findAll());
        userValidator.validate(user, bindingResult);

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "user_edit";
        }

        User userFromDB = userService.findById(user.getId());
        if (!user.getFirstName().equals(userFromDB.getFirstName())) {
            userFromDB.setFirstName(user.getFirstName());
        }
        if (!user.getLastName().equals(userFromDB.getLastName())) {
            userFromDB.setLastName(user.getLastName());
        }
        if (!user.getEmail().equals(userFromDB.getEmail())) {
            userFromDB.setEmail(user.getEmail());
        }
        System.out.println("form password length: " + user.getPassword().length());
        if (user.getPassword().length() != 0 && !bCryptPasswordEncoder.matches(user.getPassword(), userFromDB.getPassword())) {
            userFromDB.setPassword(user.getPassword());
            System.out.println("Changed password");
        }
        String currentHighestRole = getHighestRole(userFromDB.getUserName(), userService);
        String newHighestRole = getHighestRoleFromUser(user);
        System.out.println("Role set for current user = " + userFromDB.getRoles().toString());
        System.out.println("Role set for new user = " + user.getRoles().toString());
        if (!currentHighestRole.equals(newHighestRole)) {
            // Ensure that at least one Super User remains
            if (currentHighestRole == "SUPER_USER") {
                List<User> userList = userService.getAllUsers();
                int countOfSuperUsers = 0;
                for (User u : userList) {
                    if (getHighestRoleFromUser(u).equals("SUPER_USER")) countOfSuperUsers++;
                }
                if (countOfSuperUsers <= 1)
                    return "redirect:/users/viewAll?alert=error&message=Cannot reduce Super User's role. At a minimum, there must be at least one Super User within the application.";
            }
            // Create new set of roles for user
            Set<Role> newRoleSet = new HashSet<>();
            for (Role role : roleRepository.findAll()) {
                if (newHighestRole.equals(role.getName())) {
                    newRoleSet.add(role);
                    System.out.println("Setting highest role to: " + role.getName());
                    break;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("New role set looks like this: " + newRoleSet.toString());
            userFromDB.setRoles(newRoleSet);
        }
        userService.save(userFromDB);
        System.out.println("Highest role attribute on page = " + getHighestRole(user.getUserName(), userService));


        User newUser = userService.findByUsername(userFromDB.getUserName());
        System.out.println("Password After Save:" + newUser.getPassword());
        return "redirect:/users/view?id=" + user.getId();
    }
```

I should also add that my intent is for a SUPER_USER to be able edit anything about a user, including the password, but if the password fields are left blank then the password would remain unaltered.

Comment: Are you getting `BadCredentialsException`?

Comment: @vox - I am not, I get no feedback at all in the logs actually.

Comment: How do you determine the credentials are invalid, by HTTP status code? Any chance the new role has restricted access to resources?

Comment: The login page is returned (by redirection I'm guessing) with an error parameter. I also have the defaultSuccessUrl set in the WebSecurityConfig class. I have it set up now so that all roles have access to all things. And on top of that, it doesn't matter what role I alter it from or to, I still get the same issue, like I can modify the role from USER to SUPER_USER or from SUPER_USER to USER with identical results.

Comment: @KenHall You already posted the line, where you change your password: `user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));`. That's the reason. Don't change it.